# When implementing Runnable

Tags: java, multithreading

I need:
1. There are hot threads (they are always present, their number is known beforehand) and free threads (interrupts when a timeout expires).

I implement.
1. Class HotThread implements Runnable.
2. Class FreeThread extends HotThread (added a timer). 
3. Class ThreadPool as a planner. Has methods: addFreeThread(), cancelTask(int id).

My addFreeThread looks like this:

```
public void addFreeThread() {
        FreeThread ft = new FreeThread(timeout);
        Thread t = new Thread(ft);                
        ft.startTimer(t);
    }
```

Now I start to implement cancelTask:

```
public void cancelTask(int id) {
        ... // get Thread threadToCancel from the ThreadPool.
        threadToCancel.interrupt();        

    }
```

Than looks great. But the timer is still running in a separate thread. Timer is started in an instance of FreeThread class which I seem to have lost. I knew it when I started a free thread. But now I don't know where to find it.

That implementing of Runnable confuses me a lot. Maybe I can extract ft from the thread? Seems impossible. Shall I keep it in a ThreadPool. Looks troublesome as I am already keeping HashMap with the thread and its id there. I wouldn't like keeping another HashMap for keeping ids and their fts.

Could you give me a hint?

Comment: @Roberto Sánchez, no, I wouldn't say that. I need help on how to cancel a timer here. Whereas more general questions are discussed there.

Comment: Why not let the free thread run its own timer? That way it can cancel itself when its timer has expired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way I know of to get a `Thread`'s `Runnable` target at runtime. You can either extend `Thread` instead of implementing `Runnable`, or you can keep a map of your `FreeThread`s separately.

Answer (score 0):

Your `FreeThread.startTimer(Thread t)` method receiving the handle to the thread, save it and use it later to interrupt/cancel.  Your ThreadPool would then just delegate the interrupt/cancel to FreeThread or simply ask FreeThread for the saved thread handle.